# Qt containers inside non QObject

Tags: c++, qt, containers

After working some times with Qt containers and switch back to c++ stl I have found that I'm much more comfortable with Qt containers. Sometimes write stl seems me like resolving rebus in a very verbose way.

So I'm just wondering if there are some side effects in using instances of Qt Containers inside some non QObjects derivate

Comment: C++11 should make using STL containers much nicer, with stuff like `auto` variable type (lifesaver for iterators) and a for-each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, take a look at the different classes you want to have and check if there are any dependencies. For example, `QList`doesn't depend on any specific Qt Objects, is not a `Q_OBJECT` as far as I'm aware and should be good to go. The same probably goes for all the other container classes listed [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/containers.html).

What you **do** have to care about is licensing though. As this is code available under very specific rules, you cannot simply take these classes and use them in your commercial applications, for example. - Edit: Well you can, as long as you dinamically link them, of course. I didn't mean to say "it's not possible" but to have the emphasis on the "simply".

Comment: Uhm, Qt currently is also LGPL licensed, I don't see many problems in those regards...

Comment: @MatteoItalia which is true, still in that case you have to dynamically link to the classes, for example. LGPL is good, but it's not a "do whatever you want" license.

Comment: @Aerius: of course, my point was that it's not true that you can't "take these classes and use them in your commercial applications"; there are some (quite relaxed) restrictions, but Qt *can* be used for free in commercial applications.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I admid I worded it badly. I use them myself that way, so I should've worded it differently. Going to edit accordingly.

Comment: @Aerius: *It is not true that LGPL requires dynamic linking*. It's a common myth. All you need is for the customer to be able to relink your objects with their own Qt. The way it's done is by providing the objects, usually in a static library (.lib/.a). I'm tired of hearing this myth over and over again. It's not helpful, it's misleading, it may drive people away who'd otherwise use Qt.

Answer (score 2):

Qt containers can be used with "regular" objects without problems; still, keep in mind that they do not exploit some C++ features that STL containers use, so they may place additional requirements on your classes.

For example, `QVector` (as well as other Qt containers) needs a default constructor, and, when adding an element, it does a default construction + assignment, while STL uses placement new to use just the copy constructor; also, from C++11 STL containers support move semantics, while currently Qt containers just copy the objects around.

These are less of a problem for many Qt objects, since "big" Qt objects typically have a "default" invalid state and use implicit sharing semantics (so default construction, copy constructor and assignment are typically cheap), but may be a problem if your objects have costly copy (which may come from embedding STL containers, that have "full copy" semantics).

Also, if you plan to distribute your programs in some way, you should consider if it's worth to bring in a quite heav-ish dependency like Qt just for container classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the correct includes, you should be able to use them!

Answer (score 1):

Qt containers are completely unrelated to QObject functionality. Qt itself is using lots of containers of non-QObject-derived classes - `QStringList` is a common example. Qt itself is also using containers in methods in non-QObject-derived classes.